# Can i create 1 contact importer for twitter which will grab my frnd emails.?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-oauth

Respected All ,

I have a task to grab the emails of my frnds from twitter using php or CURL , what should i do to achieve this target ...!!!

Please refer this link Facebook importer and twitter importer working successfully on this link check this out

http://www.adiinviter.com/forums/

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to grab your friends emails from Facebook, it would be easy to write a Facebook App, authorize it to access your account and grab the emails. The same would be true for Twitter but, unfortunately, according to their documentation, they don't serve their users emails by api calls, so I think it's not possible.

If you wanna check further, take a look at their api documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1